# How do small icons appear on wikipedia?

Tags: html, css, wikipedia

I was looking at the source code of wikipedia and I noticed for small icons like this (look at the small pdf icon)

[image]

For icons like this there should an `<a href>` tag somewhere linking the small pdf icon's image. But I looked at source and I couldn't find anything.

[image]

I was just curious how do these small icons appear then?

Comment: You can check the styles, background-image for that anchor tag, you'll see the pdf image there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For icons like this there should an `<a href>` tag somewhere linking the small pdf icon's image.

No, there shouldn't. The link goes to the PDF. There is no link you can click on to view the icon by itself.

> I was just curious how do these small icons appear then?

It's a background image on the link element.

Comment: How can I view the background image to the link element through developer tools?

Comment: Scroll the pane in the bottom right of your screenshot.

Comment: Found it thank you very much. :)